# C#: Need for help on encrypting connection string in app.config and save it there and decrypting it and use?

Tags: c#, encryption, app-config

I need help on encrypting connection string in `app.config` and save it there and decrypt it for use.

Comment: A reference implementation is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46405204/421695).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aspnet_regiis.exe -pef` for that.
See [Encrypting the connection string in ASP.NET V2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/07/29/421063.aspx)
and [Encrypting Web.Config Values in ASP.NET 2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx) articles for further explanations.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do protection manually, you can use class `ProtectedData`. Some code:

```
class ConnectionStringProtector
{
    readonly byte[] _salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };  // Random values
    readonly Encoding _encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    readonly DataProtectionScope _scope = DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine;

    public string Unprotect(string str)
    {
        var protectedData = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
        var unprotected = ProtectedData.Unprotect(protectedData, _salt, _scope);
        return _encoding.GetString(unprotected);
    }

    public string Protect(string unprotectedString)
    {
        var unprotected = _encoding.GetBytes(unprotectedString);
        var protectedData = ProtectedData.Protect(unprotected, _salt, _scope);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(protectedData);
    }
}
```

here's a simple test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var originalConnectionString = "original string";

    var protector = new ConnectionStringProtector();

    var protectedString = protector.Protect(originalConnectionString);
    Console.WriteLine(protectedString);
    Console.WriteLine();

    var unprotectedConnectionString = protector.Unprotect(protectedString);
    Console.WriteLine(unprotectedConnectionString);

    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to finish");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Li0liQ's comment, you can use the command line program that comes with the .NET Framework 2.0+ `aspnet_regiis`. Check out the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx)