# c# How to encrypt SQL Server connection string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, connection

I want to make a client that connects to a SQL Server and has full access.

How do I make it so others wont see the connection string for the SQL Server and access it via other db editors? I know that .NET apps can be decompiled so I'm afraid for my server.

Comment: Put the connection string in the config file and encrypt it. If this is a web application it is easy to encrypt using _aspnet_regiis_ with the _-pe_ argument; not so easy for app.config files. Alternatively you could but obfuscate your code, but I think that security by obscurity is one of the least effective methods.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a **not-so-secure** reference implementation of a simple connection string encryption/decryption mechanism.

First of all, encode your connection string by using the Base64 encoding scheme.

**Unencoded Connection String:**

```
server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS2012;database=testdb;uid=testuser;pwd=supersecret
```

**Base64 Encoded Connection String:**

```
c2VydmVyPWxvY2FsaG9zdFxTUUxFWFBSRVNTMjAxMjtkYXRhYmFzZT10ZXN0ZGI7dWlkPXRlc3R1c2VyO3B3ZD1zdXBlcnNlY3JldA==
```

After this, the corresponding line in your `App.config` file should look like this.

```cs
<add name="TestDb" connectionString="c2VydmVyPWxvY2FsaG9zdFxTUUxFWFBSRVNTMjAxMjtkYXRhYmFzZT10ZXN0ZGI7dWlkPXRlc3R1c2VyO3B3ZD1zdXBlcnNlY3JldA==" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Finally, modify your `DbContext` to be able to create database connections by using the encoded connection string.

```cs
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class TestDb : DbContext
    {
        public TestDb() : base(CreateConnection("TestDb"), true)
        {
        }

        static DbConnection CreateConnection(string dbName)
        {
            string encodedCs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbName].ConnectionString;
            string decodedCs = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedCs));
            return new SqlConnection(decodedCs);
        }
    }
}
```

As you've noticed, this implementation uses the Base64 encoding scheme which can easily be reversed by the end users if they know what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

A publicly available client with full db rights is usually never a good idea so you might want to rethink that.

Here's a nice MSDN article referring to your problem:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.110).aspx

If you deploy the client to Azure you could also store confidential config information separate from your app from within the portal.

Some more ideas:

Retrieve the connection string via separate remote service and handle it using a SecureString instance.

Or just don't give the client a connection string at all by hiding the entire SQL db behind a service wall.

Answer (score 0):

Using certificates is always a great way to avoid having to store secrets in configuration.

SQL Azure has a new feature that allows you to use a certificate to access your database. See this link for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/ (section 7.3)